# By what I can replace <ripple ..> in android with api lower than 21?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-styles

In android with api version < 21 by what i can replace  tag that was introduced in api 21 ? for exemple I have this xml in my drawable folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="@color/al_ripple_material_light">
  <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
    <color android:color="@android:color/white" />
  </item>
</ripple>
```

Doesn't matter if i will not have the ripple effect in version lower than 21.

Comment: By nothing. Put that `xml` in `/values-v21`, the alternative xml for APIs lover 21 to the ordinary `/values`.

Comment: thanks, but what will be the content of the ordinary xml ?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, if you still want have ripple effect, please use some library.
If you still want to keep this xml and replace ripple tag, just put this xml file in drawable-v21 folder, and xml with normal tag in drawable folder.

Comment: thanks GiaLe ! was thinking the same, but with normal tag i can use ? (i m very new to android)

Comment: can you tell me what is the purpose of this drawable ? change color of button or view on click?

Comment: honestly i don't know, i copy it from some library that i try to backport to kitkat. name of the file is item_background_material_light if it's can help

Comment: at least you have to know that what are you doing with this drawable, if no, just leave it as blank xml or try ( this xml for click on view, replace color with each state)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>

Comment: ooh ok, i replace ripple with shape, maybe it's will be ok?

Comment: ok or not ok depend on which effect do you want on your UI. all tags is ok for run. you need to know where it take effect

Comment: @ user7905708, the ripple tag is used to create a button background to achieve the ripple effect when the button is clicked.